# How to perform a task after flask app starts?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute a task after the app does the binding with the port so it doesn't get killed by Heroku for taking too long on startup. I am aware of the existence of `before_first_request` however I would like this action to be performed as soon as possible after the app startup without requiring a request.

I am loading an object as an attribute of the app object (because I need to access it across requests) and this object has to initialize in a weird way (it checks if a file exists and downloads it if it doesn't and afterwards it performs a bunch of computations).

Currently I'm doing this in the following way:

```
def create_app() -> Flask:
    ...
    with app.app_context():
        app.model = RecommenderModel()  # This downloads a pretty heavy file if it isn't there
        app.model.load_products()  # This performs a bunch of calculations
    ...
    return app
```

This initializes the app properly (as tested locally) however Heroku kills it (Error R10) because it takes too long.

Is there a way to do this asynchronously? When I tried to do so the app context got lost.

Edit: Additional information regarding what I'm doing:

The `RecommenderModel` object models the logic of a recommendation system. As of now, the recommendations are based on vector cosine similarity. Those vectors are extracted using pre-trained word2vec embeddings (which is the large file that needs to be downloaded). The conversion from products to vectors is handled by a `Preprocessor` class.

The Recommender Model initialization looks like this:

```py
class RecommenderModel(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.preproc = Preprocessor()
        self.product_vector: dict = {}

    def load_products(self) -> None:
        for product in Product.get_all():
            self.product_vector[product.id] = self.preproc.compute_vector(product)
```

The Preprocessor initialization looks like this:

```py
class Preprocessor(object):
    def __init__(self, embeddings: str = embeddings) -> None:
        S3.ensure_file(embeddings)
        self.vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(embeddings)
```

The `S3.ensure_file` method basically checks if the file exists and downloads it if it doesn't:

```py
class S3(object):
    client = boto3.client('s3')

    @classmethod
    def ensure_file(cls, filepath: str) -> None:
        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            return
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME')
        cls.client.download_file(bucket_name, filename, filepath)
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but it should almost certainly happen during your _build phase_, not at runtime.

Comment: Can you specify what task you're doing and provide the code?

Comment: @Simba I added more information and code regarding what I'm doing, please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: @Chris I moved the downloading part to the build phase. I discovered however that what's taking most of the time is not downloading the file (it is very fast as the s3 bucket and the heroku app are in the same region) but the other tasks.